# Weird callstack leading up to CreateRemoteThread

Tags: multithreading, winapi, windbg, callstack

I am having a hard time understanding the callstack below.

```
ntdll!NtCreateThreadEx+0xc
KERNELBASE!CreateRemoteThreadEx+0x1f0
kernel32!CreateThreadStub+0x27
MyModule!_beginthreadex+0x87
```

Sorry I cannot reveal any more of it because of proprietory issues but I believe we should be able to make at least partial sense just with this. That was the state of one the threads spawned by a third party library inside a crash dump I was looking at. (the thread itself had nothing to do with the problem I was investigating.)

What condition can possibly cause a call to `_beginthreadex` to end up in Create**Remote**Thread? The MSDN doc for the API does not give me any clues (the word 'remote' doesn't even appear on that page.)

I have symbols for the third party library and the callstack is definitely legit.

**Update:**

Interesting. If I disassemble backwards from the spot `CreateThreadStub` is supposed to return to, I see the following instructions:

```
call    dword ptr [MyModule!_imp__CreateThread (573701a0)]
cmp     eax,ebx
```

When I do:

```
0:048> dds MyModule!_imp__CreateThread l1
573701a0  75b5cf30 kernel32!CreateThreadStub
```

and when I disassemble `CreateThreadStub`, I do see it calling `CreateRemoteThread`. This is all very confusing!

Comment: this is absolute usual stack for create thread. *CreateRemoteThread[Ex]* is **always** called when you create thread.

Comment: @RbMm Really? I always thought CreateRemoteThread creates a thread in the address space of a *different* process?

Comment: yes, really. *CreateRemoteThread[Ex]* is always when you call *CreateThread* or *_beginthreadex*. you ask `What condition can possibly cause ` - this is unconditionally. **always**

Comment: @RbMm Thanks! I am not afraid to admit I never knew that! Guess I should delete this question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function description on MSDN is a bit misleading:

> Creates a thread that runs in the virtual address space of another process.

The first line of remarks is a much better summary of `CreateRemoteThread`:

> The `CreateRemoteThread` function causes a new thread of execution to begin in the address space of the specified process.

At least with this description, it's clear that you can create a thread in the local process using `CreateRemoteThread`, merely by specifying the current process.  Also note this in `CreateRemoteThreadEx` remarks:

> The `CreateRemoteThreadEx` function causes a new thread of execution to begin in the address space of the specified process. The thread has access to all objects that the process opens. The `lpAttribute` parameter can be used to specify extended attributes such as processor group affinity for the new thread. **If `lpAttribute` is NULL, the function's behavior is the same as `CreateRemoteThread`**.

When you think about the transition to kernel-mode, and the fact that `CreateRemoteThreadEx`, by choice of parameters, can do everything that `CreateThread` or `CreateRemoteThread` can do, and the maintenance cost of testing correctness and security of each syscall, it makes sense to provide only one syscall with a superset of all the abilities, and have all these functions use it.

Comment: I realize this now. Should've tried what Thomas Weller shows below before posting! Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 3):

The stack you posted is the normal stack. Compile the following C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void test(void *param)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(test, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Start WinDbg
2. Open the executable
3. At the initial breakpoint, set a breakpoint

   ```
   0:000> bp KERNELBASE!CreateRemoteThreadEx
   0:000> bl
        0 e Disable Clear  7485b060     0001 (0001)  0:**** KERNELBASE!CreateRemoteThreadEx
   0:000> g
   ```
4. See that the `main()` method calls `CreateRemoteThreadEx()` when it hits the `_beginthread()` method:

   ```
   0:000> k
    # ChildEBP RetAddr  
   WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
   00 00f7f714 0f7ba3cd KERNELBASE!CreateRemoteThreadEx
   01 00f7f758 000f255f ucrtbased!_beginthread+0xed [d:\rs1\minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\startup\thread.cpp @ 174] 
   02 00f7f844 000f2cbe ThreadStartStack!main+0x2f [c:\users\t\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\threadstartstack\threadstartstack\threadstartstack.cpp @ 19] 
   03 00f7f858 000f2b20 ThreadStartStack!invoke_main+0x1e [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 64] 
   04 00f7f8b0 000f29bd ThreadStartStack!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x150 [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 253] 
   05 00f7f8b8 000f2cd8 ThreadStartStack!__scrt_common_main+0xd [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 296] 
   06 00f7f8c0 752362c4 ThreadStartStack!mainCRTStartup+0x8 [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp @ 17] 
   07 00f7f8d4 77370fd9 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
   08 00f7f91c 77370fa4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
   09 00f7f92c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
   ```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I should've done this myself. I just didn't realize all requests to create a thread ultimately gets sent down to CreateRemoteThreadEx as Ben Voight noted above.